# Activate CSS Pseudo using Checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-class

I am not sure if this is even possible. But basically I am using Pseudo elements to slide in an additional piece of content. This works perfectly. However, what I also want to do is make this appear and stay if a checkbox or radio button is ticked. Is it possible to trick a Pseduo state using a checkbox.

Basically I want a checkbox to trigger an active Pseduo state.

Can anyone suggest the best way of doing this without altering the current setup too much

```
.client-link.has-content:target .client:after,
.client-link.has-content:active .client:after,
.client-link.has-content:focus .client:after {
left:50%;
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'll want to put your element with the `:after` CSS directly after the checkbox and use the adjacent sibling selector `+` to target it (like in my answer), or you can put it anywhere after the checkbox and use the general sibling selector `~` to target it.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .foo:after {
  content: 'foo';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<div class='foo'></div>
```